# NSString remove a non braking space

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Let's say I get a string "123 4,56" from the following code (I have a Russian local at the moment which has comma as a default separator rather than a dot), how do I remove the space from it which in reality is a non breaking space and the standard code like [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; will not work:

```
NSString* amount = @"1234.56";
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_UK"]];
NSNumber *num = [formatter numberFromString:amount];
NSString* str = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.2F", [num doubleValue]];
NSLog(@"Str Value: %@", str);
NSString *newStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSLog(@"New Str Value: %@", newStr);
```

The output I get is:

```
Str Value: 1 234,56
New Str Value: 1 234,56
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is I get a string from the server which is a currency (i.e. 123.45) and I need to display that in the UITextField. The problem is that I can't just display the value as it comes from the server because it is dependant on the user local. If the user has a UK local that works fine, however if the user has a Russian local I need to display a comma instead of a dot, thus basically what the code above does. The issue I however get is that after converting the string from one local to another there is an annoying space added to it that I'm trying to get rid of.

**Solution based on Doro answer**

```
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@""];
```

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` will only do it at the beginning and at the end of the string.

Comment: What does this line return? `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

Comment: @Nishant it returns the original string with the space

Comment: Your code with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` worked for me on my iPad with iOS 9.1

Comment: are you sure? you are aware of the fact that str will not change, but the result will be in newStr?

Comment: @luk2302 yes I'm aware, just trying to figure out not why it works for others now

Comment: please, see my answer (edit section) that is not whitespace, that is special character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds strange, did you check that that was exactly whitespace character?

i can offer this snippet for striping input characters using scanner:

```
- (NSString*)   stripInputValue:        (NSString*) inputValue
{
    NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString
                                       stringWithCapacity:inputValue.length];
    
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:inputValue];
    
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSString *decimalSymbol = [formatter decimalSeparator];
    
    NSCharacterSet *validCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[@"1234567890" stringByAppendingString:decimalSymbol]];
    
    while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        NSString *buffer;
        if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:validCharacters intoString:&buffer]) {
            [strippedString appendString:buffer];
            
        } else {
            [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
        }
    }
    return strippedString;
}
```

Be careful - if you want to support multiply locales - some locales uses '.' as separator, some ','. You can check this programmatically, if needed.

**EDIT**

Also please note that iOS doesn't use a space as a separator but a non-breaking space (U+00A0) for `localizedStringWithFormat:` so that is your problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Doro I think you're right, I'm just now trying to figure out how to strip this non braking space

Comment: the following is working: [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@""];

Answer (score 0):

The first line should have worked

```
NSString* newStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

But just in case it didn't, I have another way for you:

```
NSString* newStr2 = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

**UPDATE:**

Instead of playing with the locale manually, you should use dynamic locale method for your requirement.

Replace: `[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_UK"]];`

By:

```
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];             
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Comment: You are right my bad, can you have a look at my updated question please

Comment: I tried your code on iPhone 6 iOS 9.1 Simulator. Got this output: `Str Value: 1,234.56
 New Str Value: 1,234.56`
WHAT IS YOUR DESIRED RESULT?

Comment: please, see my answer (edit section) that is not whitespace, that is special character

Comment: @DarkAPI: Please chk my updated answer for your requirement.

Comment: @Nishant the reason I define a UK locale is because I can parse a 123.45 string with UK locale (which uses a dot rather than comma). However I later call NSString localizedStringWithFormat to get back the value in the local locale